# Using Kotlin with Dagger

Tags: dependency-injection, dagger, kotlin, dagger-2

What's the best way to use Dagger to inject dependencies into classes, especially zero-arg constructor classes like Activities, with Dagger? Will Dagger 2 possibly bring improvements to the situation?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Since **Kotlin M13** release, a new property has been especially added in order to **support dependency injection** (like with Dagger 1&2) and other frameworks.

It's called **lateinit** property. Taken from the documentation:

```
 class Example {
            @Inject
            lateinit var bar: Bar 
 }
```

In a nutshell, **bar** has no initializers but is declared as a non-null type. If you try to read it before the initialization, an exception is thrown.
Otherwise, once it's initialized using Dagger, it can be used as a normal property.

Everything is well explained in the [language doc](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#late-initialized-properties) and you can also check the [blog post relative](http://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2015/09/kotlin-m13-is-out/#more-2502) to the M13 release there.

Comment: How to lateinit on primitive type like Int, Long in kotlin

Answer (score 13):

I wasn't updating my answer for a while and it got outdated. Also noticed here new answer from @Ben that works for M13/M14.

Decided it would best if I redirect all of you interested to my template project which I try to keep up to date with latest Kotlin and Dagger 2 versios. [Kotlin + Dagger 2 sample](https://github.com/damianpetla/kotlin-dagger-example)

I am describing there how to inject objects, including multiple annotations etc.

Comment: Do you have a sample project I can look at?

Comment: @cypressious I have created a template project. https://github.com/damianpetla/kotlin-dagger-example

Answer (score 1):

Dagger relies on annotation processing, which is not supported yet in Kotlin, as far as I know. But they say, it is planned. And while, you can either extend java classes with Dagger dependencies, or try some reflection based injection framework - Guice, Roboguice

Comment: Annotation processing is supported. Issue is in '$' symbol in generated code

Comment: @EugenMartynov Did you manage to work it? Dagger 1 and other libraries, relying on annotation processing.

Answer (score 0):

for using dagger annotations in Kotlin
1- // dagger add dependencies in app level

```
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.38.1'
kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.38.1'
```

add in app level/gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}
```

now you can use annotations like `@Inject @Component` etc

```
class Test{
    @Inject
    lateinit var name: String
}
```